# How to bind a request to a specific network interface with Rust Hyper HTTP client?

Tags: rust, hyper

I have a Linux server with multiple network interfaces. Each interface has its own IP address.
How to force HTTP requests to use a specific interface by specifying its IP address? Just like [curl --interface](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) command line option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to build your own `HttpConnector` probably starting from [the vanilla connector](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/src/client/connect.rs), perhaps using [`net2::TcpBuilder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/net2-rs/net2/struct.TcpBuilder.html).

This is definitely something that seems like it should be easier, perhaps specified in the config. You might want to open an issue for hyper or submit a pull request if you implement it yourself.